# Can I use Intent to launch the same Activity (Android)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am currently working on an app which takes a number of user entries. I want to have each EditText field on its own page, and instead of having a seperate activity for each entry, I wanted instead to call the same activity again. Is this possible, and if so, is it a feasible solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but I don't think it is the way to go. Basically if the next input is a separate action then it deserves its own activity.

That is the way you are supposed to do it.

You could store the gathered values either in the `Application` class as a temporary storage or you can save it using `SharedPreference`. However if it is only temporary data I advice you to use the `Application` class rather than writing it to a file.

Comment: I'm actually storing the inputs in a String array, and i have an int i (to access the elements of the array) that increments every time the user presses "next"

Answer (score 0):

I would think that if your UI doesn't change (significantly) between views, then reusing your activity and displaying different data seems fine to me (I do this myself).

I keep an object on the `Application` class that contains a list of the sub-objects (Inputs in your case).

On the top level object, I keep the index of the current index.
This works very well, does not leak memory and is very fast to render as I swipe through my pages.